# How to put two pictures on the same level in a word file (.docx) python

Tags: python, docx

I want to put the logo and the barcode on the same level and not one on top of the other.The logo should stay at the very left and the barcode at the very right of the word file.Here is my code , thank you:[image]

```
import uuid 
import pandas as pd
import pyqrcode 
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches


qr=pyqrcode.create(str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-',''))
qr.png('somecode.png')

df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('Komplette- 
GastAccountFHZugangsdatenFertig.xlsx'))

Attributes=['Name', 'Vorname ', 'Geschlecht', 'Adresse (in Marokko)',
       'Telefonnummer', 'E-Mailadresse', 'Studiengang', 'Semester']


document = Document()

document.add_heading('Informationen.',level=0)

document.add_picture('Informatik_Logo.png',height=Inches(1.0))


p = document.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()


p_format=p.paragraph_format

p_format.left_indent=Inches(4.5)
r.add_picture('somecode.png',width=Inches(1.0))


table=document.add_table(len(Attributes),2,style='LightGrid-Accent1')


for i in range(len(Attributes)):
        row=table.rows[i]
        row.cells[0].text=Attributes[i]
        Infos=df[Attributes[i]]
        string=str(Infos[49])
        row.cells[1].text=string



document.save('sample.docx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can help you with that,just add one sentence into your code

```
r.add_picture('somecode.png',width=Inches(2.0))
```

that is all. just write the sentence one more time.and if you want more picture in the same level, all you need to do is that add the sentence. i tried and it works to me.

there is my test code

```
dc = Document()

run = dc.add_paragraph().add_run()
run.add_picture("./picture/danilise.jpg", width=Inches(1.1))
run.add_picture("./picture/danilise.jpg", width=Inches(1.3))
run.add_picture("./picture/danilise.jpg", width=Inches(1.5))

dc.save("test1.docx")
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I see in [the documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/shapes.html), `python-docx` only currently supports *inline* pictures, not *floating* pictures, which means that you can only get the look you currently have. From the docs:

> At the time of writing, python-docx only supports inline pictures. Floating pictures can be added. If you have an active use case, submit a feature request on the issue tracker. The Document.add_picture() method adds a specified picture to the end of the document in a paragraph of its own.

Based on that last sentence, I think what you're trying to do is currently impossible. A workaround might be to insert a table with one row and two columns, and insert an image in each cell.

Comment: Maybe i can create a table and put the 2 pictures on it